# How can unit-tests use SmartGWT classes?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit, smartgwt, jsni

In our SmartGWT web application, we pass our domain objects from the server to the client and back (via GWT serialization). To show/edit the data at client side in a DynamicForm or a GridList, we have to convert it into a [Record](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/Record.html) (or [ListGridRecord](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGridRecord.html)) and after editing back into our domain objects.

I would like to write a **unit test** for this conversion method, but a straightforward attempt in JUnit fails, since the record's [`getAttribute`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/core/DataClass.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) and [`setAttribute`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/core/DataClass.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods are implemented by [`JSOHelper.getAttribute`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/JSOHelper.html#getAttribute%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject,%20java.lang.String%29)/[`JSOHelper.setAttribute`](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/JSOHelper.html#setAttribute%28com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), which are static methods declared as `native` and implemented by JSNI in JavaScript, thus only usable on the client side, when compiled to JavaScript.

We get an UnsatisfiedLinkError when using these methods from JUnit, as the native methods are not implemented there.

**Any ideas how I could test these classes?**

These critical methods could be easily implemented by a simple HashMap (or maybe a LinkedHashMap, if the attribute order is important) - actually a JavaScript object is about that, if only looking at the data part, not the methods. Thus I just think about providing an alternative implementation of some selected SmartGWT classes (mainly JSOHelper) with Java implementations instead of the JavaScript ones.

But am I really the first one who has this problem? Am I simply too stupid to find the existing solution?

Comment: Related (but doesn't really help here): [GWT: Best practice for unit testing / mocking JSNI methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543462/gwt-best-practice-for-unit-testing-mocking-jsni-methods)

Answer (score 0):

If you have used a MVP or MVC pattern in your code, just mock the view code with something like [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and test all the rest of the application.  To test the view code you will need to use something like [Selinium](http://seleniumhq.org/)  I don't think gwtTestCase would work with smartGWT since it is just a gwt wrapper around js code.

Comment: We are using MVP, but this class I want to test is actually a part of the view (or can be considered as such). It concerns only pure data classes (no GUI one), but data classes represented by JavaScript objects, which is the problem here.

Comment: Maybe you could write a java version of the methods that are not resolved.

Comment: Yeah, that was my idea, but I hoped someone else did it already, thus my question here.

Comment: I made a blog about unit testing the client side of a smartGWT application, if you want to have a look (I'm using selenium) : http://noobdevelopper.tumblr.com/